# Error with using add.indicator() in Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am really despairing of this problem and I haven't found any solution. If i remove the last call to add.indicator applyIndicators and thus the backtest will function, but this way I always run in the runSum error message.

Someone with an idea?

```
# load necessary packages
library(quantstrat)
library(quantmod)

# initialize basic settings
initdate = "1999-01-01"
from = "2003-01-01"
to = "2015-12-31"
currency("USD")
stock("SPY", currency = "USD")
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

tradesize <- 100000
initeq <- 100000
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat"

# load market data from yahoo finance
getSymbols ("SPY", from = from,
            to = to, src = "yahoo",
            adjust = TRUE,
            index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))

# initialize portfolio, account, orders and strategy
rm.strat(strategy.st)

initPortf(portfolio.st,
          symbols = "SPY",
          initDate = initdate,
          currency = "USD")

initAcct(account.st,
         portfolios = portfolio.st,
         initDate = initdate,
         currency = "USD",
         initEq = initeq)

initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)

strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

# add the strategy's backbone: indicators, signals and rule
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 20),
              label = "SMAClose")
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Op(mktdata)), n = 20),
              label = "SMAOpen")
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Hi(mktdata)), n = 200),
              label = "SMA200")
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 10),
              label = "SMA10")

applyIndicators(strategy.st, SPY)
Fehler in runSum(x, n) : ncol(x) > 1. runSum only supports univariate 'x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates your x variable is multivariate. If you run `head(x)` you will see the series'

```
    Browse[1]> head(x)
               SPY.Close SMA.SMAClose
    2003-01-02  70.37356           NA
    2003-01-03  70.58992           NA
    2003-01-06  71.83404           NA
    2003-01-07  71.65631           NA
    2003-01-08  70.62083           NA
    2003-01-09  71.71812           NA
```

The problem stems from the label "SMAClose" in your first indicator. The `Cl()` function from quantmod uses grep and a pattern "Close" to identify Close prices. By the time you try to create your 4th indicator, you have 2 columns with the name "Close" in your mktdata object...so both are returned and SMA errors out. Simply naming the first indicator `"SMACl20"` or anything without the word "Close" will work fine for your above code. HTH.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Quantstrat is frustrating sometimes;)